# What is an analytical decompiler?

Tags: decompiling, decompiler

IntelliJ incorporates Fernflower, a Java decompiler made by JetBrains.

On its [GitHub page](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine) you can read the following:

> Fernflower is the first actually working analytical decompiler for Java and probably for a high-level programming language in general.

What does this mean? What is an *analytical decompiler*? How does it differ from other types of decompilers?

Answer (score 2):

An *analytical* [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) is one that analyzes compiled output and then figures out what source code would best match it, rather than trying to be the exact inverse of a traditional compiler. Sometimes this is necessary in case of optimizing compilers or obfuscated bytecode.